# How to keep fps rate constant in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have 3 question.

1. How to keep fps rate constant(almost) in cocos2d.When lots of CCSprite created and removed within a small interval like (5-8) per second is it possible to keep frame rate lmost constant??
2. Is `[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES]` is enough or i should also use

   CCTexture2D *texture = [sprite texture];
   [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture: texture];
3. The following Part of code is responsible for my frame drop.How to accomplish same task in better way-

   id fadeout = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1.4f];

> id call = [CCCallFunc
>   actionWithTarget:self
>   selector:@selector(RemoveSmashedSprite:)];

```
CCSequence* sequence= [CCSequence actions:fadeout, call, nil];
[smash runAction:sequence];
```

and

```
-(void)RemoveSmashedSprite:(id)sender
{


    CCSprite *sp = (CCSprite *)sender;



    [self removeChild:sp cleanup:YES];  

}
```

This is called 5-8 times per second.So the frame rate goes down.Can any one help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that the "smashed sprite" in question is probably one of a number of sprites visible on the screen, more than likely sharing the same texture (part of a sprite sheet perhaps, or all the same image, etc?).

If this is the case, I would recommend allocating the number of sprites your games requires to have on screen and rather than "destroy" (remove them, re-create them) you should "re-use them".

Store a reference to all the CCSprite's in an NSMutableArray, populate this array with the number of sprites you think is appropriate (how many sprites are removed per second? how many sprites are added per second? how many sprites are on the screen to start? - use the answers to these questions to determine the most appropriate size of your array).

Then, rather than removing the sprite as a child, simply [sprite setVisible: NO] to hide it, then ... when you need to display a new one on screen, use the next "available" (hidden) sprite in the array (keep track of the last "used" sprite with an index, and simply increment it by 1 to find the next "available".  Once the index exceeds the bounds, reset it to 0 - at this point, that sprite should have been "smashed").  Once you have the next "available" sprite, change it's properties (position, scale, texture?, visibility) and apply any actions that are appropriate (don't forget to "stop all actions" on it when "smashing it" - this is what "cleanup: YES" does).

If your game does not allow you to go around in a "circle" like this, because the user decides what may or may not be visible by interacting with the sprites in a varied order then you can store a reference to the "smashed sprites" in a separate array (while keeping them in the original array as well - then you can just pick anyObject from the "unused" array, remove it from that array and then alter it as mentioned above).

This should reduce your frame rate drops dramatically, as you won't be creating and destroying sprites all the time.

---

Another thing that may be occurring is that you are using different images, and each image is stored separately (image1.png, image2.png, image3.png) and the creation/destruction of these is causing the textures to be removed and re-added ... to resolve this, create a sprite sheet and add the sprite sheet to the Texture Cache, then create your images with 'spriteFromSpriteCacheName:@"image1.png"'